# Not able to align layout at bottom properly

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am new to android. I am creating a layout as same as link http://prntscr.com/es7oko . Now my problem is I have created this layout using relative layout and createed this last "sign/signUp" layout in linear layout but when I put align_parent_bottom property to linear layout then relative layout height changes to full screen but i have specified wrap_content height. Help me to have same layout.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@mipmap/bg_sign_in">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcom"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_32_margin"
        android:text="@string/Welcome"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallText"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/welcom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_8_margin"
        android:text="@string/quote"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/smallTextHalf"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/smallText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/halfQuote"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1"

        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSignIn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/SignIn"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSignUp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/SignUp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

I got this using above code : http://prntscr.com/es7qcq

Comment: don't use textview for signin and signup. Use buttons and give them transparent background

Comment: I want to put layout at bottom. @VivekMishra . I am not asking about textview or buttons

Comment: do you know that button extend from textview? so what is the difference in what you are saying? What you are proposing is just the style

Comment: I am saying this if I use align parent bottom then my layout height leads to match parent instead of wrap. How can I achieve the same as per in screenshot

Comment: why do you use weight as 1 in the LinearLayout inside the Relative layout? Do you know what the weight is for? you do not need it

Comment: you want to achieve the layout shown in the first image for both orientations?

Comment: Yes, I want it for for portrait only . Weight was written just by mistake. @KostasDrakonakis

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layout_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_home_ll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
       </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout for the bottom portion:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/txtSignIn"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Sign in"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:background="@color/color_white"></View>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/txtSignUp"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/color_black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

output:

[image]

Comment: android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" will leads to increase banner area check my another screenshot link. That is my only problem

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` is needed to align the view..and your ` android:layout_height="wrap_content"` so it will increase only if the text size or text value insrease..if you don't want it to increase you can use: a specific height `android:layout_height="50dp"`

Answer (score 0):

**#** If you don't want to align `signIn` and `signUp` buttons at the bottom of screen, then you need to set `fixed height` for banner `RelativeLayout`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sign_in">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcom"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_32_margin"
            android:text="@string/Welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smallText"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/welcom"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_8_margin"
            android:text="@string/quote"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smallTextHalf"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/smallText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/halfQuote"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSignIn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/SignIn"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSignUp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/SignUp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

**#** If you want to align `signIn` and `signUp` buttons at the bottom of screen, then you need to set `height` as `wrap_content` for banner `RelativeLayout` and need to set `LinearLayout` attribute `layout_alignParentBottom` value `true`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_sign_in">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/welcom"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_32_margin"
            android:text="@string/Welcome"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smallText"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/welcom"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_8_margin"
            android:text="@string/quote"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/smallTextHalf"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/smallText"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/halfQuote"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSignIn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/SignIn"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSignUp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="@string/SignUp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~